# How can I control in what thread I show my popup

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I use a control that is a popup window. I have a methodes that show and hide it and I need to implement a functionality that will prevent show and hide my popup in different threads. Can I show my popup in not UI thread?

**Update**

The main goal of my question is:

It's not important from what thread the method Show starts, the Method Hide should be in the same thread. How to implement this?

```
 public void Show()
        {
            IsShown = true;
            if (this.ChildWindowPopup == null)
            {
                this.ChildWindowPopup = new Popup();
                    try
                {
                    this.ChildWindowPopup.Child = this;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The control is already shown.");
                }
            }       
            if (this.ChildWindowPopup != null && Application.Current.RootVisual != null)
            {
                // Configure accordingly to the type
                InitializeProgressType();
                    // Show popup
                this.ChildWindowPopup.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }

 public void Hide()
        {
            IsShown = false;
            // Restore system tray
            SystemTray.IsVisible = currentSystemTrayState;
            this.progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            this.ChildWindowPopup.IsOpen = false;
            }
```

Comment: Can you simply save Thread.CurrentThread when you show and check if it is the same when you hide?
Still - I would argue that this question indicates another problem. Why would you want to check the thread? If the goal is to show progress bar for some operation - you could create some object (token) to associate the progress bar with an operation. I don't see why you would want to manage threading the way you are suggesting other than to debug another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Generally working on UI components can only be done in UI thread. If you want to block your specific popup from being started from UI threads you would need to provide an interface to launch it that internally checks the thread it has been executed from - perhaps using SynchronizationContext or Thread classes, but in the end - it will need to show the Popup by invoking a method on UI thread.